Dovecot Mailserver moves mails with "List-Unsubscribe" header to junk, although no spam settings configured
I have my own mailserver setup with postfix and dovecot on an Ubuntu 20 server. The setup is very standard (postfix using mbox files) and has been working nicely for a long time. However, there is an annoying thing going on regarding spam mails. Some mails are always being put into the Junk folder. For example, all automatic notifications from github.com land there. The common culprit of all affected mails seems to be that they have something like List-Unsubscribe: in the header (seems to be common for auto-notification mails).
Here's the output of dovecot -n (my config):
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.8.0-1041-aws x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
# Hostname: myhost.com
auth_failure_delay = 1 secs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_worker_max_count = 10
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 0
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
local 1.1.1.1 {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.com/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
}

The normal mail lands in the file /var/mail/user. The Junk mail file is in /home/user/mail/Junk, here I can find the affected mails. The junk mails there have this additional header, that seems to be added by dovecot: X-Keywords: $Junk $Filtered 
Now, what I don't understand is why those mails are moved into the Junk file. I don't have any plugins for dovecot configured that deal with spam (no sieve) and I couldn't find any config setting that is dealing with Junk / Spam other than the namespace section in the config above. All my settings are mostly default, so I suspect there to be some default setting messing with my setup.
Would appreciate any hints!
/e: I've already grepped all postfix and dovecot configs for anything related to "spam" or "junk", but couldn't find a single thing.
In case it's related to postfix and not dovecot as suggested by the comments, here my /etc/postfix/master.cf:
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil

scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}


You have configured something in dovecot, procmail, postfix or similar to handle those e-mails. Dovecot would be least likely; postfix would be more likely.

That's the tricky part. It seems like something is configured that way. But neither did I explicitly do that, nor can I find the implicit configuration for it. But I'll keep digging into postfix some more.

It's probably a milter. Do a grep -ir junk /etc/postfix to see if you can find it... :)
